# setting an array element with a sequence error in python

Tags: python, numpy

I started studying python and I have a question for the program. I am writing
as the first step I thought of creating a big matrix and a big vectors where I will put some smaller vectors and  smaller matrices. I created at random.

I have created a function that returns the max eigen values of those small matrices and save them in a vector. Also I created a function that basically does the multiplication of the transpose of my small vectors with the small matrices that I had randomly calculated. However when I try to pass the value of the multiplication, I get the following error

> "setting an array element with a sequence."

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as lg
import math

N=5;
n=3;
Qs=np.zeros((n,N*n))
xs=np.zeros(n*N)
qs=np.zeros(n*N)
grads=np.zeros(N*n)
Lfi=np.zeros(N)
pis=np.zeros(N*n)
pi=np.zeros(N)
phat=np.zeros(N)
j=0;
gamma=np.zeros(N)
def gradient(Q,x) :
  return x.transpose().dot(Q)

def eigen(Q):
  val, vec = lg.eig(Q)
  return np.amax(Q)

for i in range(0,N):
  A = np.random.randint(10, size=(n,n))
  Qs[0:n,j:j+n] += A
  x = np.random.randint(10, size=(n))
  qs[j:j+n] += x
  x = np.random.randint(10, size=(n))
  xs[j:j+n] += x
  j = j+n
  Lfi[i] = eigen(A)
  grads[i] = gradient(A,x)
```

Why do I get the error for the gradient and not for example at the Lfi?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. By the way, the formatting of the code looks broken. Also, is there any particular reason this was tagged Anaconda?

Comment: This seems like a rather big project for someone who is just starting to learn a new language. Handling vectors, matrix, numpy arrays, transposing, broadcasting, etc.. is not easy. Maybe try to start with a simpler project?

Comment: First of all thank you for your replies. I ve written all the code i have so far. The reason i used the anaconda tag is because i am writing it in anacoda. I m sorry if i tagged it for no reason or for a wrong reason. Also i looked some stuff on datacamp and online and they seemed basic(for example print loops etc) so i wanted to dive into more complex stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your `gradient` function returns something else than what is expected by `grads`. From the error message I can tell that `grads` is numpy array which is not as forgiving as default python list. It has a type associated with it and it requires every element to be of that type.

e.g.

```py
a = np.array([0] * 10)
print(type(a[0]))
```

this will tell you that the type of elements in this array is `numpy.int64` (obviously there are many types and this is just a one of them). If you try to assign some value of a different type, python will try to coerce it to `numpy.int64`. But obviously, there is no sensible (general) way to coerce another array or matrix to a single number.

If you try

```py
a[0] = [1, 2, 3]
```

then you will receive the error mentioned by you

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

---

And why don't you receive the error when calling `eigen` function? Well, because it just returns a single value, not an array. `np.amax(Q)` returns a single value if you don't specify `axis` parameter which is set to `None` by default.

Comment: I edited and posted all the code i have written so far. Perhaps if i pass it as an object then i will not have a problem? Basically i want to create a loop where i will save a smaller random vector to a bigger one. I thought of storing all my vectors into a big one so i can use them later in my program and just by playing with the index i go from the one vector to the next one

Comment: If you want to store matrices (2D tensors) in another numpy array then that array needs to be a 3D tensor (having 3 axes along which you can place values). So it needs to be of a shape `(m, n, o)`. Right now, you are using `(n,N*n)` - 2 dimensions. Working with tensors is not the most simple stuff and unless you know what you are doing (unless you know that you need them), you probably be better off storing those 2D numpy matrices in the good old python list. (also note that in a 3D tensors - all 2D matrices need to be of the same shape)